# Not being able to locally view webpage on Tomcat server?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have a Java 2E project that essentially handles things on a website. The xhtml code is fine, and on my laptop I am able to run the Apache Tomcat server in Eclipse, and open up my web browser and go to http://localhost:8080/web-app. When I do this, it opens up the index.html webpage I created just fine.

However, when I try to do this on my Mac (opening Eclipse, importing the exact project from my flash drive all the same), it gives me an Apache error saying "The requested resource could not be found."

Does anybody know what I could be doing wrong here? If you need more details, please let me know. In Eclipse on my Mac, whenever I try to go to run as..., a "run on server" option is not available like it is on my windows laptop. i have to manually go to "run configurations...run on server...apache tomcat server...and click run, then nothing happens."

Comment: to fill in some details: is there a plugin you use normally for tomcat in eclipse?  Does your Mac eclipse have the same plugin?  The Apache error is perhaps in the console of eclipse - or is "it" a browser?  Any other details behind that?

Comment: did you import the .war file?? or imported the existing project?.
Try importing the .war and replace the java and jsp files

Comment: @BrianHenry To answer some of your questions, 1) I usually don't use a plugin for Tomcat, I just add the Tomcat server in Eclipse by going to the server tab next to the console, right click -> add server -> and point the tomcat directory which i installed. I do this for both computers. 2) When i try to access localhost in chrome i get an error saying the resource is not found. The console in Eclipse doesn't notify me of any errors. I assume the server is running fine but I'm not attaching my project to the server somehow.

Comment: @Konza I imported the existing project into my workspace from my flash drive. Does it make a difference If I import the war file instead? I will try this tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: There are project specific configuration files. Since you are porting it from widows to mac there may be mismatch in the filesystem path representaions. I am not sure. So the safer way is to import the war file.